# How to write SQL Query to remove a given set of special characters from a selected column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a table [ABCTable]

When I query with

```
SELECT [XYZ] from [ABCTable]
```

there is a possibility that [XYZ] set of rows returned might contain - [~], [!], [@], [#], [$], [%], [^], [&], [*], [,], [.] , [?].

Is there a way to write **just a SQL Query** (not stored procedure or sub routines) to ensure these characters are removed while selecting the needed data ?

Comment: Create Function that will do it for you.

Comment: any reason you can't just use `REPLACE` for each character?

Comment: In SQL Server this is usually done using lots of nested `replace` because it's lacking `translate` and `RegExp_replace` :-(

Comment: Not quite true @dnoeth [TRANSLATE (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @Larnu: Great, finally available in SQL Server 2017, but why did MS implement it differently, so it can't be used to remove characters (without knowing a character which doesn't exist in the column and adding a final `replace`)?

Comment: @dnoeth that's a question a can't answer I'm afraid.

Comment: @Larnu: I didn't expect an answer, of course only MS can answer that, I was just ranting :-)

Comment: @dnoeth should have realised thay was rhetorical. Hadn't noticed how bad the language in the documentation was either; it reads like broken English.

Comment: @jtate No need to use `REPLACE()` for each character, check my answer there.

Comment: @Larnu It seems like there is a way to do it ;)

Comment: For this problem I would use [AlphnumericOnly](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/String+Function/141686/) if you want strip on non-alphanumeric or [PatExclude8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/T-SQL/117890/) for more functionality. Both will blow the doors off of RedExp_replace. As an alternative you can use TRANSLATE as previously mentioned but I suspect this will perform more poorly than a nested REPLACE; nested REPLACE is certainly the way to go if you can get away with it. The problem with SQL Server's Translate is that you cant do this: `TRANSLATE('xyz','')`

Answer (score 4):

Do you want something like

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  Value VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO T(Value) VALUES
('.A*B$C@'),
('D#E$,F'),
('.G,H*I@$'); 

DECLARE @Chars VARCHAR(45) = '@$.,*#';

SELECT *, REPLACE(TRANSLATE(Value, @Chars, REPLICATE(' ', LEN(@Chars))), ' ', '') Result
FROM T;
```

**Returns:**

```
+----+----------+--------+
| ID |  Value   | Result |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 | .A*B$C@  | ABC    |
|  2 | D#E$,F   | DEF    |
|  3 | .G,H*I@$ | GHI    |
+----+----------+--------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d70f0375c7f88c00b755def7ad2e6f67)**

**Note:** If you have WhiteSpaces there I suggest that you use `CHAR(9)` instead as

```
REPLACE(TRANSLATE(Value, @Chars, REPLICATE(CHAR(9), LEN(@Chars))), CHAR(9), '')
```

Comment: Exactly as I wrote in my comment, you need to nest it in a Replace, hopefully there's no space within the data...

Comment: This solution works for the sample data you provided but I would not use a space as the dummy REPLACE value. Obviously values that have spaces will get messed up. I'd go with CHAR(1) or another character that is less common.